# onclick event does not work with JSF

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I'm trying to make onclick() work on Primefaces. The first item "wildcard" works on-load of the page but all other p:menuitem does not work at all.

jQuery:

```
function ShowLuceneInfo(part){

        jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #fuzzySearches').addClass('displayNone');
        jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #proximitySearches').addClass('displayNone');
        jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #rangeSearches').addClass('displayNone');
        jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #boostingATerm').addClass('displayNone');
        jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #booleanOperators').addClass('displayNone');
        jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #grouping').addClass('displayNone');
        jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #escapingSpecialCharacters').addClass('displayNone');
        jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #wildcardSearches').addClass('displayNone');

        jQuery('.ui-menu-item-label').removeClass('ui-state-selected');

        if(part == 'fuzzy'){
            jQuery('.luceneInfoMain div').removeClass('displayBlock');
            jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #fuzzySearches').removeClass('displayNone');
            jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #fuzzySearches').addClass('displayBlock');
            jQuery('#luceneID\\:luceneID\\:fuzzy').addClass('ui-state-selected');

        }
        else if(part == 'proximity'){
            jQuery('.luceneInfoMain div').removeClass('displayBlock');
            jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #proximitySearches').removeClass('displayNone');
            jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #proximitySearches').addClass('displayBlock');
            jQuery('#luceneID\\:luceneID\\:proximity').addClass('ui-state-selected');
        }
        else if(part == 'range'){
            jQuery('.luceneInfoMain div').removeClass('displayBlock');
            jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #rangeSearches').removeClass('displayNone');
            jQuery('.luceneInfoMain > #rangeSearches').addClass('displayBlock');
            jQuery('#luceneID\\:luceneID\\:range').addClass('ui-state-selected');
```

Primefaces code below each item on the p:menuitem should make display the page on their right:

```
    <s:div styleClass="w30p floatL inlineBlock">
    <s:div styleClass="inlineBlock marB10 floatL w100p">
        <a4j:form id="luceneID">
            <p:menu id="luceneMenu" keepOpen="true">
                <p:submenu label="Supported" styleClass="fontBold">
                    <p:menuitem id="wildcard" styleClass="ui-state-selected"
                        value="Wildcard Searches" onclick="ShowLuceneInfo('wildcard')" />
                    <p:menuitem id="fuzzy" value="Fuzzy Searches" 
                        onclick="ShowLuceneInfo('fuzzy')" />
                    <p:menuitem id="proximity" value="Proximity Searches"
                        onclick="ShowLuceneInfo('proximity')." />
                    <ui:remove>
                    <p:menuitem id="range" value="Range Searches"
                        onclick="ShowLuceneInfo('range')" />
                    <p:menuitem id="boosting" value="Boosting a Term"
                        onclick="ShowLuceneInfo('boosting')" />
                    </ui:remove>
                    <p:menuitem id="boolean" value="Boolean Operators"
                        onclick="ShowLuceneInfo('boolean')" />
                    <p:menuitem id="grouping" value="Grouping"
                        onclick="ShowLuceneInfo('grouping')" />
                </p:submenu>
            </p:menu>
        </a4j:form>
    </s:div>

<s:div styleClass="inlineBlock floatL w100p">
        <a4j:form>
            <p:menu keepOpen="true">
                <p:submenu label="Not Supported" styleClass="fontBold">
                    <p:menuitem id="escape" value="Escaping Special Characters"
                        onclick="ShowLuceneInfo('escape')" />
                </p:submenu>
            </p:menu>
        </a4j:form>
    </s:div>
</s:div>

<s:div styleClass="floatL w69p marL1p luceneInfoMain">
    <rich:panel id="wildcardSearches" styleClass="marB10">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <s:div styleClass="panelHead inlineBlock">
                <s:span styleClass="breadCrumbText floatL marL5">
                    <h:outputText value="Wildcard Searches"></h:outputText>
                </s:span>
            </s:div>
        </f:facet>

        <s:div>
            <p class="marB10">Supported wildcards are *, which
            matches any character sequence and ?, which matches any single
            character. Note this query can be slow, as it needs to iterate over
            many terms.</p>
            <p class="marginBottomTen">In order to prevent extremely slow
            WildcardQueries, a Wildcard term should not start with one of the
            wildcards * or ?.</p>

            <rich:dataTable value="#{luceneSyntax.getWildcardSearches()}"
                var="_row" rowKeyVar="mainRowKey" rowClasses="odd-row, even-row"
                styleClass="marB10 w100p height100">

                <rich:column width="20%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{luceneSyntax.getColumnHeader1()}"
                            styleClass="fontBold"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value=" #{_row.get(0)}" escape="false" styleClass="txtAC fontBold" />
                </rich:column>

                <rich:column width="50%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{luceneSyntax.getColumnHeader2()}" styleClass="fontBold"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value=" #{_row.get(1)}" escape="false" styleClass="txtAL valignT" />
                </rich:column>

                <rich:column width="30%">
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{luceneSyntax.getColumnHeader3()}"
                            styleClass="fontBold"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value=" #{_row.get(2)}" escape="false" styleClass="txtAL valignT"/>
                </rich:column>

            </rich:dataTable>
        </s:div>
    </rich:panel>

    <rich:panel id="fuzzySearches"
        styleClass="marB10 displayNone">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <s:div styleClass="panelHead inlineBlock">
                <s:span styleClass="breadCrumbText floatL marL5">
                    <h:outputText value="Fuzzy Searches"></h:outputText>
                </s:span>
            </s:div>
        </f:facet>

        <s:div>
            <p class="marB10">Fuzzy searching will find a word even
            if it is misspelled. This can be useful when you are searching text
            that may contain typographical errors.</p>

            <rich:dataTable value="#{luceneSyntax.getFuzzySearches()}"
                var="_row" rowKeyVar="mainRowKey" rowClasses="odd-row, even-row"
                styleClass="marB10 w100p height100">

                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{luceneSyntax.getColumnHeader1()}"
                            styleClass="fontBold"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value=" #{_row.get(0)}" escape="false" styleClass="txtAC fontBold"/>
                </rich:column>

                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{luceneSyntax.getColumnHeader2()}"
                            styleClass="fontBold"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value=" #{_row.get(1)}" escape="false" styleClass="txtAL valignT"/>
                </rich:column>

                <rich:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        <h:outputText value="#{luceneSyntax.getColumnHeader3()}"
                            styleClass="fontBold"></h:outputText>
                    </f:facet>

                    <h:outputText value=" #{_row.get(2)}" escape="false" styleClass="txtAL valignT"/>
                </rich:column>

            </rich:dataTable>
        </s:div>
    </rich:panel>
```

Comment: `<p:menuitem onclick="alert('Test')"/>` is working like a charm at by application - are you sure the event is called and not that your JS is buggy?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve (in non-technical terms)

Comment: i'm trying to create a tip page, a modal. Basically would have two panels. Left panel contains items -  

1. Wildcard Searches
2. Fuzzy Searches
3. Proximity Searches
4. Boolean Operators
5. Grouping.

On-load of the page the Wildcard search is pre-selected then the contents on the right panel would appear corresponding the item selected.  On-load opens the right panel just correct but the other item would not appear at all when click. I guess on-click even doesn't work?

Comment: On-load of this tip page, <p class="marB10"> properly as the page display it, but all other items on the left panel would not load any item on the right at all when clicked.

I've edited post to contain items that should be displayed on my right panel when corresponding item is clicked on the right.  Thanks  @Kukeltje

Comment: I've decided to make changes on the code, instead of using jQuery i've decided to use javascript instead.

on my javascript:

function ShowwildcardSearches() {
  document.getElementById('wildcardSearches').style.display = 'block';
....

then on the 'onclick' event:

<p:menuitem id="wildcard" value="Wildcard Searches" 
  onclick="ShowwildcardSearches()" />